# Search and replace regular expression in Open Office calc

Tags: regex, openoffice.org, expression, openoffice-calc

I've got something like this (in Open Office Calc):

```
Streetname. Number
Streetname. Number a
```

etc.
Now I want to delete everything in front of the number.
So I need to do a search and replace I guess.
    ^.*?([0-9])
this one matches Streetname. Number .. but what should I put in the replace field?
If I do the search and replace, it deletes everything within the datafield :(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In *Search for* field, write the following regex:   `(.*?[:space:])([0-9]+)`

And in *Replace with*, write: `$2`

That means that you search for:

1. any characters followed by a space
2. one or more digits.

Replace all that with `$2` - the reference to the digits.

It will replace `Streetname. Number 24` with `24`. Why did you put `a` in your example?

Comment: Yes, great .. 
$2 and the regex worked :)

Thank you very much

Comment: Oh .. yes .. didn't seem that obvious :-S